# Writing to Arduino's serial monitor box

Tags: arduino, sms

I'm trying to send SMS using GPRS attached to Arduino.

I have this code:

```
// send an SMS!
    char sendto[21], message[141];
    flushSerial();
    Serial.print(F("Send to #"));
    readline(sendto, 20);
    Serial.println(sendto);
    Serial.print(F("Type out one-line message (140 char): "));
    readline(message, 140);
    Serial.println(message);
    if (!fona.sendSMS(sendto, message)) {
      Serial.println(F("Failed"));
    } else {
      Serial.println(F("Sent!"));
    }
```

I tried to send, and it is working perfect, but I have to use the serial monitor box to enter the number and the message, and the library is using only this method. I want the code to run by itself without entering anything in the box.
Is there is any way so I can do that? I mean something like writing automatically to the box from the code.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Comment: Is it really not obvious that you need to set `sendto` and `message` yourself? Or what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take out the parts of the code that read the line from the Serial monitor and replace with lines of code that either have the data it needs hard-coded or has some other way to get that data.  You really haven't shown enough of the code to help you figure out how to do that.